# Finding the expected value of a variable given the CDF and supports

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals

So a C.D.F is given:

$G(p)= \frac {1}{a}\left(1-(1-a) p^{-\frac{1}{n-1}}\right) $

Over the support:

$[(1-a)^{n-1},1]$

The author then goes on to proceed and state that given this information it is trivial to derive the following:

$E(p)= -\frac{(1-a) \log (1-a)}{a} $,                            if n =2

$E(p) = 
\frac{1-a}{a (n-2)}\left(1-(1-a)^{n-2}\right)$, if n is greater than 2

It may be trivial but I get different results. My procedure thus far has been the standard expected value thing, I multiplied by p and took an integral, clearly i'm doing something wrong :(.

To be clear, i'd like to know if a) This author is correct, and/or b) how to get there

Comment: I don't know the details of what you did. If we *differentiate the cdf* to find the density, we  can then multiply by $p$ and integrate. (There is also a way to avoid differentiating, but that will in this case not save much time.)

Comment: Goodness its been so long I knew I forgot something. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.  So I take it things went well. The details are not hard. True, there are slightly ugly constants, but the differentiation and integration only involve powers of $p$.